# Proving a function is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and let $f:X\to\mathbb R^+$ be a measurable function such that $$\mu(\{x\in X\,\colon\,f(x)>t\})>\frac{1}{1+t},\; \forall t>0.$$ Prove then that $f$ is not integrable.

I've tried to derive a contradiction, however my original plan to use Chebyshev inequality to get such an absurd turned out to be useless..

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance, Guido

Comment: $$ \int_X f d \mu > \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{k}{k+1} = \infty$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_X f d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R_+}\mu(\{x: f(x)>t \})dt > \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is measurable, then
$$
\int_X f \, d\mu = \int_0^{+\infty} \mu \left( \left\{ x \in X \mid f(x)>t \right\} \right)\, dt
$$
See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation).

Comment: Hey Siminore! This time I beat you by 30 seconds! _And_ I have an additional term!

Comment: Which question? +1, cause you gave the same answer ;-)

Comment: Sorry, +1 to your *answer* :-)